# React Native Input Losing Focus after a keystroke

Tags: reactjs, react-native, input, redux, react-router

So I am having a problem after just typing 1 key into a textfield the textfield is re-rendering and losing focus.

Here are some snippets of code, if you need more do not hesitate to ask:

Here is the DiaryInput Component:

```
const DiaryInput = ({label, value, onChangeText, placeholder, secureTextEntry, autoCorrect, autoCapitalize}) => {
const {inputStyle, labelStyle, containerStyle} = styles;
return (
    <View style={containerStyle}>
        <Text style={labelStyle}>
            {label}
        </Text>
        <TextInput
            secureTextEntry={secureTextEntry}
            placeholder={placeholder}
            autoCorrect={autoCorrect}
            autoCapitalize={autoCapitalize}
            style={[inputStyle, {height: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 50 : 25}]}
            value={value}
            onChangeText={onChangeText}
            keyboardType={'numeric'}
            /*editable={false}*//>
    </View>
)};
```

Here I am using the Component (within render()):

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {ScrollView} from 'react-native';
import {DiaryInput} from "../DiaryInput";
import {DiarySlider} from "../DiarySlider";
import DiaryHeader from "../DiaryHeader";
import {TextArea} from "../common/TextArea";
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {
    carbsChanged,
    fatsChanged,
    proteinChanged,
    dailyWeightChanged,
    hoursSleepChanged,
    feelLevelChanged,
    wodChanged,
    notesChanged,
    journalChanged,
    dateChangedLeft,
    dateChangedRight,
    getDiaryInfo,
    saveDiaryInfo
} from "../../actions/DiaryActions";

class DiaryPage extends Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        // this.props.getDiaryInfo();
        // this.state.currentDateString = dateString;
        this.props.currentDate = new Date();
    }

    onCarbsChanged(text) {
        this.props.carbsChanged(text);
    }

    onFatsChanged(text) {
        this.props.fatsChanged(text);
    }

    onProteinChanged(text) {
        this.props.proteinChanged(text);
    }

    onDailyWeightChanged(text) {
        this.props.dailyWeightChanged(text);
    }

    onHoursSleepChanged(text) {
        this.props.hoursSleepChanged(text);
    }

    onFeelLevelChanged(value) {
        this.props.feelLevelChanged(value);
    }

    onWODChanged(text) {
        this.props.wodChanged(text);
    }

    onNotesChanged(text) {
        this.props.notesChanged(text);
    }

    onJournalChanged(text) {
        this.props.journalChanged(text);
    }

    onRightChanged(date) {
        this.props.dateChangedRight(date);
    }

    onLeftChanged(date) {
        this.props.dateChangedLeft(date);
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <ScrollView>
                <DiaryHeader
                    text={this.props.currentDate.toLocaleString("en-US")}
                    onLeft={this.onLeftChanged(this.props.currentDate)}
                    onRight={this.onRightChanged(this.props.currentDate)}/>
                <DiaryInput
                    label={"Carbs"}
                    value={this.props.carbs}
                    onChangeText={this.onCarbsChanged.bind(this)}/>
                <DiaryInput
                    label={"Fat"}
                    value={this.props.fats}
                    onChangeText={this.onFatsChanged.bind(this)}/>
                <DiaryInput
                    label={"Protein"}
                    value={this.props.proteins}
                    onChangeText={this.onProteinChanged.bind(this)}/>
                <DiaryInput
                    label={"Daily Weight"}
                    value={this.props.dailyWeight}
                    onChangeText={this.onDailyWeightChanged.bind(this)}/>
                <DiaryInput
                    label={"Hours Sleep"}
                    value={this.props.hoursSleep}
                    onChangeText={this.onHoursSleepChanged.bind(this)}/>
                <DiarySlider
                    label={"Feel Level"}
                    value={this.props.feelLevel}
                    onChangeText={this.onFeelLevelChanged.bind(this)}/>
                <TextArea
                    label={"WOD"}
                    value={this.props.wod}
                    onChangeText={this.onWODChanged.bind(this)}/>
                <TextArea
                    label={"Notes"}
                    value={this.props.notes}
                    onChangeText={this.onNotesChanged.bind(this)}/>
                <TextArea
                    label={"Journal"}
                    value={this.props.journal}
                    onChangeText={this.onJournalChanged.bind(this)}/>

            </ScrollView>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps({diary}) {

    const {carbs, fats, proteins, dailyWeight, hoursSleep, feelLevel, wod, notes, journal, currentDate} = diary;

    return {carbs, fats, proteins, dailyWeight, hoursSleep, feelLevel, wod, notes, journal, currentDate};
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
    carbsChanged,
    fatsChanged,
    proteinChanged,
    dailyWeightChanged,
    hoursSleepChanged,
    feelLevelChanged,
    wodChanged,
    notesChanged,
    journalChanged,
    dateChangedLeft,
    dateChangedRight,
    getDiaryInfo,
    saveDiaryInfo
})(DiaryPage);
```

Here I have the function for when text Changes:

```
onHoursSleepChanged(text) {
        this.props.hoursSleepChanged(text);
    }
```

The Action:

```
export const hoursSleepChanged = (text) => {
return {
    type: HOURS_SLEEP_CHANGED,
    payload: text
}};
```

Reducer:

```
case HOURS_SLEEP_CHANGED:
        return {...state, hoursSleep: action.payload};
```

And I think that's all that is needed...

The action and reducer is working properly... Just the input is losing focus after a single keystroke...

Please let me know if you have an idea on this. I have been struggling to find the cause.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you include the entire file where you're using the `DiaryInput` component.

Comment: Please Check the latest now! @alecrobins

Comment: I would like to see how `DairyPage` is rendered

Comment: It is very difficult to help you troubleshoot with so much code to look through. I think you'll have far better luck if you created a reduced test case. Remove as much of the code as you can, until you're left with the minimal amount of code needed to reproduce the specific issue you're needing help with.

Comment: Did you try rendering with the `key` attribute for all components?